# Why regex does not return overlapped matches

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression:

```
[0-7]{2}
```

For the following string `234212`, I get three matches:

```
23   
42
12
```

I don't understand why I don't get also `34`, `12`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?=([0-7]{2}))
```

The above regex captures every valid pair in group 1 , I have used the positive look-ahead to achieve this as this helps to match without moving the cursor forward.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3iNkiT/1/)